# Materialized views with partitions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

Can we create materialized views with partitions in PostgreSQL (version 10.7) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot, and it is not easy to think of a use case for that.

True, some carefully designed queries can be faster on a partitioned table, but most queries become slower.

You can work around the “deficiency” by creating a table and filling it with `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

Comment: > a use case for that.

Aggregations / reporting e.g. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/0974f793-e5aa-71a9-aec1-01b7bed7162b%40gmail.com